# how can i use regex to get a certain string of a file

Tags: linux, bash

with linux bash shell , how can i use regex to get a certain string of a file

by example:

for filename *.tgz
do

"get the certain string of filename (in my case, get 2010.04.12 of file 2010.01.12myfile.tgz)"

done

or should I turn to perl

Merci

frank

Comment: get 2010.01.12 or 2010.04.12 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
FILE=2010.01.12myfile.tgz

echo ${FILE:0:10}
```

gives

```
2010.01.12
```

Comment: I guess he needs d=${FILE:0:10}

Comment: that's what i did yesterday finally, but thanks all the same~~

Answer (score 1):

with bash, for the simplest case, if you know what you want to get is a date stamp, you can just use shell expansion

```
#!/bin/bash

for file in 20[0-9][0-9].[01][0-9].[0-9][0-9]*tgz
do
 echo $file
done
```

else, if its anything before the first alphabet,

```
for file in *tgz
do
 echo ${file%%[a-zA-Z]*}
done
```

otherwise, you should spell out your criteria for the search.

Comment: sorry to my bad expression, i mean to get the string that i want not the file . 

the shell is like this: 


for filename *.tgz
do 
  #get the certain string of filename (in my case, get 2010.04.12 of file 2010.01.12myfile.tgz)
done

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/sh
a="2010.04.18Myfile.tgz"
echo ${a%%+([a-zA-Z.])}
```

bash' regexp are quite powerful (at least compared to standard sh or command.com :-))

Comment: hi, can't get this done
i just want to sign '2010.04.18' to a variable

Comment: you can say b=${a%%...} as in the example above

Comment: You would need to set your shebang to `#!/bin/bash` and have `shopt extglob` in order to use `+(...)`.